# IE table rowspan compatibility

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I have my table with overlapping rowspans, but in IE it doesn't seem to want to do that, it keeps pushing the bottom right cell so that second last cell on the right side is the same height as the middle one on the left side, but in Firefox it doesn't do that.

In every browser, except IE it looks like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/wUWFH/6/

But in IE it looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wUWFH/7/

As you can see in the bottom right side, the last cell is taller than its left-side pair, but in IE it shows them both the same height.

Is there a CSS to fix this? IE compatibility is really starting to get frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your problem iwht IE 7, try applying `border-collapse:collapse;` on table via css

Comment: That still doesn't fix it. I added border-collapse: collapse and empty-cells: show and it didn't do anything. The cells still aren't lined up right.